# don't work Mysql connection in Laravel project by xampp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my project opens normally, but when I want to open the database in phpMyadmin, it says:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'examplee'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have added my own login and password on the .env file which does not run on phpMyadmin.

I tried to change config.inc.php and changed the login and password there to the one that was defined in the .env file, but it didn’t work anyway, changed host 127.0.0.1 to localhost, but that didn’t help either.

please help. As I understand it, this is probably a simple problem.
I'm new in this area, and please explain a little bit in detail ..))

Thanks a lot....

Comment: Are you able to connect to the `mysql` db?

Comment: Did you create that user/host in MySQL? The user needs to be created before it can be used.

Comment: Xampp creates a default user with username `root` and a blank password.

Comment: in .env I add login and password and when try connect xampp-phpMyAdmin with my login and password, appears that Error.  @PeterSmith

Comment: no I have complete project, that have a database files, but can't run a query. I use xampp databes... @aynber

Comment: Database files do not a database user make. Note that PHPMyAdmin is just a web interface to log into the database, not the database itself, but you can use that to check and see what users are set up with `select user, host from mysql.user`

Comment: @aynber sorry.... could you say me how can I do it??